# How to add multiple ads in Facebook Instant Articles using wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I want to display multiple ads on Facebook instant articles. I found this code, which I tried manually and its working.

```
  <section class="op-ad-template">

        <!-- Ads to be automatically placed throughout the article -->

        <figure class="op-ad">
          <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250&adslot=1" height="300" width="250"></iframe>
        </figure>

        <figure class="op-ad op-ad-default">
          <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250&adslot=2" height="300" width="250"></iframe>
        </figure>

        <figure class="op-ad">
           <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250&adslot=3" height="300" width="250"></iframe>
        </figure>

   </section>
```

Now I am trying to make it possible via Facebook Instant Article Plugin. I didn't find any setting option for these type ads.

I tried to search on google and can't find anything except this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk/transformer-rules

Please help me!

A. How to add multiple ads using **FB INSTANT ARTICLE PLUGIN** in wordpress?

B. How to add different codes using **FB INSTANT ARTICLE PLUGIN** in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `instant_articles_transformed_element` filter, in order to modify the header accordingly.

This is generally used when placing Facebook Audience Network units, but if your manual code worked, the following code should work, although you might need to play around with the query vars. Add to **functions.php** the following:

At the top of functions.php, add this:

```
use Facebook\InstantArticles\Elements\Ad;
```

And then:

```
/**
 * Adds multiple units to the Instant Article
 * 
 * @param Instant_Articles_Post $article
 * 
 * @return Instant_Articles_Post
 */
add_filter('instant_articles_transformed_element', function ($article) {
        // Create the base ad
        $ad = Ad::create()
                ->withWidth(300)
                ->withHeight(250)
                ->enableDefaultForReuse();

        // Retrieve the header
        $article->getHeader()
                // Add the first ad
                ->addAd(
                       $ad->withSource(
                                // This creates the URL https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250;adslot=1
                                add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                           'adtype' => 'banner300x250',
                                           'adSlot' => '1',
                                        ),

                                        'https://www.mywebsite.com/ss'
                                )
                        )
                )
                // Add the second ad
                ->addAd(
                        $ad->withSource(
                                // This creates the URL https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250;adslot=2
                                add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                           'adtype' => 'banner300x250',
                                           'adSlot' => '2',
                                        ),

                                        'https://www.mywebsite.com/ss'
                                )
                        )
                )
                // Add the third ad
                ->addAd(
                        $ad->withSource(
                                // This creates the URL https://www.mywebsite.com/ss;adtype=banner300x250;adslot=3
                                add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                           'adtype' => 'banner300x250',
                                           'adSlot' => '3',
                                        ),

                                        'https://www.mywebsite.com/ss'
                                )
                        )
                );

        return $article;
});
```

With that code, the plugin will take care of the rest, and it will automatically add the following code to the **head** section:

```
<meta property="fb:use_automatic_ad_placement" content="enable=true ad_density=default"/>
```

It will also add the following right before closing the **header**:

```
<section class="op-ad-template">
              <figure class="op-ad op-ad-default">
                <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss?adtype=banner300x250&amp;adSlot=1" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
              </figure>
              <figure class="op-ad">
                <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss?adtype=banner300x250&amp;adSlot=2" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
              </figure>
              <figure class="op-ad">
                <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/ss?adtype=banner300x250&amp;adSlot=3" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
              </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Its showing me blank page on the front end of my website and Facebook Instant Article options of the post are just showing loading icon. I can't see debug information or anything else.

Comment: Just edited my answer... You need to add this at the top of functions.php: use Facebook\InstantArticles\Elements\Ad;

Comment: Awesome! Now its working. Can you explain me this code ? A little bit please :) And Thank You!

Comment: Basically, what this code does is to include additional ad units after the plugin has parsed the content. The plugin then takes care of adding the appropriate code to the <head> and <header> section, as shown in my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @luqita can manual ads placement be achieved ? like I want ad to be placed at 300px from top into the instant-article